# Css float a third element with content depending on width

Tags: html, css, width, css-float

I'm doing a menu for a restaurant that they dynamiclly add. it looks like this

```
Dish Name                                            Price
Content in the dish,Content in the dish,Content in the dish,
Content in the dish,Content in the dish.
```

What i want to do is to get the blank space dotted, with . or dotted border.
But i cannot figure out how to get the css to autoadjust the width of the blank space div.
The dishnames could be longer then "dishname".
Any1 have a solution for this?

EDIT
The price and name is in 2 divs already with floats on them

```
.dishHead 
{
font-family:Verdana;
font-size: 18px;
color:#262626;  
float:left;
font-weight:200;
}

.dishPrice
{
font-family:Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
color:#262626;  
float:right;
}
```

Edit2:
The whole thing is structured as below:

a div that floats right or left
the left floating head, the right floating price, and a description below.
I need a div between the head and price without affecting the whole div it lies in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I would do it with a background image on the whole of the "heading" part then use a background color on the name and price div to cover the image however that will only work if the background is a plain colour.

In answer to your question to get a third div to take up the remaining space between the left and right divs you would use `overflow:hidden` on it so an example using a dotted border might look like this:

#### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/Q6WAx/)

**CSS:**

```
.dishHead {
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 18px;
  color:#262626;  
  float:left;
  font-weight:200;
}

.dishPrice {
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#262626;  
  float:right;
}

.spacer {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 3px dotted #000;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dishHead">Dish Name</div>
<div class="dishPrice">Price</div>
<div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="dishContent">
Content in the dish,Content in the dish, Content in the dish,
Content in the dish,Content in the dish.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could place lots of dots in an element with dishname and use the fallowing css:

```
.dishname { 
   width:400px;
   overflow:hidden; 
   white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: or alternatively if the menu is on solid color background, use images with dots as background for the dish name conatiner and make text display:inline-block with background color.

Comment: Well, only 1 problem... The name and the price is 2 separate divs. so i dont know how to do theese changes, without braking it.. Check the edit

Comment: Two separate divs are good thing, example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jWxfr/ the problem is that sometimes a dot can be cut in the middle - the bigger and bolder the font the more visible it is. But you can't account for text rendering.

Comment: Hmm, the problem is i didnt quite post my whole code.. Check edit 2 :P